# Android 5.0 - Strings displayed by their Id values on Interface - Dynamic localization failing

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop, android-resources

I have an app which updates the locale folder dynamically when the app is opened. It was working perfectly on Android versions less than 5.0.

The way I update the resources folder is below:

```
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I am trying it now on Android 5.0, the strings on the interface are shown as @number, instead by their actual value.

Any idea why this happening.

Thank you.

Comment: without seeing the `code` we cannot suggest anything. Please post what you have tried.

Comment: I recently ran into this and in my case I didn't have the english (default language) defined but other languages had the string. As soon as I added the english string to the strings.xml it worked. Check to make sure it is defined in the all languages you support.